# Как правильно достать несколько записей с бд в ларавел?

Tags: php, laravel

`$hotels = Hotel::where('id', '=', $hotel[0]->hotel_id)->paginate(10);`

Так я получу один отель по `$hotel[0]->hotel_id`. А если мне нужно достать 10 отелей например по разным `$hotel[10]->hotel_id`.
Нужно писать как-то так ?

```html
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$hotel = UserHotel::where('user_id', '=', $id)->get();
      for($i = 0; $i < count($hotel); $i++){
           $hotel[] = Hotel::where('id', '=', $hotel[$i]->hotel_id)->paginate(10);
      }
```

Comment: whereIn('id',[массив_id_отелей])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще было бы сделать вот так:

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$userHotelIds = UserHotel::where('user_id', $id)->get()->pluck('hotel_id');
$hotel = Hotel::whereIn('id', $userHotelIds)->paginate(10);
```

Но на самом деле ещё проще было бы через реляции это сделать, подсказал бы зная вашу структуру БД.

Comment: Спасибо работает. Только я не очень понял как ) потому, что во view в `$hotel` вижу только 1 запись, но выводит все.

Comment: Там же пагинатор обьект должен быть, а в нём итератор, со временем разберетесь =)